# Getting approach procedures and plates from FAA NASR data

Tags: data-request, government, transportation

I'm building a [website](https://www.arelplane.com/locations/khpn) that shows all important data for a given airport, navaid, etc, similar in content to [this one](https://nfdc.faa.gov/nfdcApps/services/ajv5/airportDisplay.jsp?airportId=khpn) and am trying to find the best way to get the data, starting with FAA data.

I've found a number of sources for different parts of the data on different FAA websites, but I think the [28 Day NASR Subscription](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/aero_data/NASR_Subscription_2020-03-26/) is the datasource I should be using. So, this brings me to three questions:

1. Is the NASR the best official source of the data I need?
2. I see DPs, ILSs, and arrivals, but where are other types of approaches, RNAV, VOR, etc.
3. Is there any relationship between the data in NASR and the approach plates, airport diagrams, etc. the FAA creates?

For clarity, I want general airport information (name, location, etc.), and links to FAA approach plates, airport diagrams, etc. for that airport, but, I want this website to be usable for navigation, so I'll need to be able to know when data is expired/active, etc. as well.